# Toggle div and expanding/compress other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm sorry this is quite a silly question, but maybe it's because of being working for a few hours, but I can't wrap my head around this. I mean, I think I can solve this by manipulating the whole div structure with javascript, but I can't help to feel there has to be a way simpler solution that I'm not thinking of.

Here's a fiddle of what I got right now:

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/42687/

```
<main class="col-sm-9 ml-sm-auto col-md-10 pt-3" role="main">
    <div class="container-fluid colindex">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9 stackem">
                <div class="card">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ route('layouts.index') }}">Index</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <h4 class="card-header">Test
                        <button class="btn btn-primary add" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover" title="test"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">bookmark</i></button>
                    </h4>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="container index">
                            <div class="row py-3 px-4">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <p></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <p></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row py-3 px-4">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <p>test</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <p>test</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row py-3 px-4">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <p>test</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <p>test</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>      
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>testlist</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

So the div which says "testlist" on the right, I got an include there with a list with links for fast access.

**Question:** What I'm trying to achieve is adding a button on this list which will toggle it. The thing is, when it's hidden, I want the other divs on the left side to expand and takes up the space on the list. When the list would be toggled again it would become like it is at the moment again.

Again, sorry for the (I'm sure) silly question, and thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `<div class="col-md stackem">`
instead of `<div class="col-md-9 stackem">`
to let bootstrap auto-adjust the width?

Comment: So then I would toggle the whole div the list is in right? I will try and post back. This is the kind of simple thing I was looking for but I guess was too saturated to think of myself. Thanks !

Comment: It should work this way, yes... When only 1 column is left with no fixed gridsize it should get fullwidth. I've tried it in your fiddle as well. (without implementing the javascript ofc - just by editing)